# RewriteCond HTTP_HOST starting with

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to write a condition in .htaccess in which all hosts starting with a word will be ignored. For instance, i want it to ignore to example.com,  example.com.br, example.com.uk, example.com.au and so on.

So far the only way i know to do this is to writing one rule for each, like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com\.au$ [NC]
```

Is there a way to write only 1 rule for all ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a single condition using regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?example\.com(?:\.(?:br|uk|au))?$ [NC]
```

Or if you may want to just use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?example\.com(?:\.|$) [NC]
```

Comment: Great ! Can you adjust it to ignore with or without WWW in the host ?

Comment: Can you please edit the answer with this www regex ?